# Is this all for Garbage Collection in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, garbage-collection

Hi I just picked up Obj-C and quite dislike its manual memory management.

I decide to go with its Garbage Collection, by adding

```
objc_startCollectorThread();//garbage collection
```

in my Main() and change the garbage collection value to [-fobjc-gc]

**So is that all I need**? So I can program "freely" like I do in Java/Python..etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you are right, but in case any iPhone programmer comes by and thinks "oh sweet!", please note that the iPhone doesn't support Garbage Collection yet (ever?). So this is the MacOS only solution.

Comment: wow. thanks for telling me that --- as I was actually addressing the iPhone platform

Comment: I kind of guessed that. Objective-C almosts equals iPhone for most people :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that `-fobjc-gc` means that you still use retain/release (when writing a Framework/library); you probably want `-fobjc-gc-only` if you want to get rid of the reference counting code completely.

Answer (score 2):

As other said, there is no garbage collection in iPhone.

If you are writing a Desktop Cocoa app, all you need is the `-fobjc-gc-only` flag, without the explicit `objc_startCollectorThread()` startup function.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, yes. This is covered in [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/GarbageCollection/Articles/gcEssentials.html). You may also need occasional calls to

```
objc_clear_stack
```

But this is optional, to ensure stack retained object lifetimes are as short as needed.